# Using Java reflection, can I access a private field of type private static nested class?

Tags: java, reflection, minecraft

I've looked through every entry related to Java reflection I can find and none seem to address the situation I'm dealing with. I have a class A with a static nested class in it, B. Class A also has as one of its fields, an array of type B, called bArray. I need to access this field from outside the class as well as the private members of the elements of bArray. I have been able to get the static nested class using getDeclaredClasses and I would normally get the private field bArray with getDeclaredFields and setAccessible but I can't seem to put it all together to be able to iterate through bArray from outside the class.

Here is an example class structure that I'm working with.

```
public class A {
    private A.B[] bArray = new A.B[16];

    private static class B {
        private int theX;
        private int theY;

        B(int x, int y) {
            this.theX = x;
            this.theY = y;
        }
        // More methods of A.B not included   
    }
}
```

I ultimately need to get at bArray and its fields theX and theY from outside of class A.

I cannot use the names of the classes like Class.forName("classname") because the code all gets run through an obfuscator and the names all change except the ones in strings of course. I can use the field order (index) but not the name due to obfuscation. I've managed to pick out all of the fields, methods and whatnot that I need except this private static nested array field.

This is the direction I've tried. The first 3 lines of this seem to do what I want but the 4th says ABArray cannot be resolved:

```
A myA = new A();
Class AB = stealNamedInnerClass(A.class);
Class ABArray = Array.newInstance(AB, 0).getClass();
ABArray myABArray = (ABArray)stealAndGetField(myA, ABArray);
```

These are the utility functions I'm referencing:

```
public static Field stealField(Class typeOfClass, Class typeOfField)
{
    Field[] fields = typeOfClass.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field f : fields) {
        if (f.getType().equals(typeOfField)) {
            try {
                f.setAccessible(true);
                return f;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                break; // Throw the Exception
            }
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't steal Field of type \"" + typeOfField + "\" from class \"" + typeOfClass + "\" !");
}

public static Object stealAndGetField(Object object, Class typeOfField)
{
    Class typeOfObject;

    if (object instanceof Class) { // User asked for static field:
        typeOfObject = (Class)object;
        object = null;
    } else {
        typeOfObject = object.getClass();
    }

    try {
        Field f = stealField(typeOfObject, typeOfField);
        return f.get(object);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't get Field of type \"" + typeOfField + "\" from object \"" + object + "\" !");
    }
}

public static Class stealNamedInnerClass(Class clazz)
{
    Class innerClazz = null;
    Class[] innerClazzes = clazz.getDeclaredClasses();
    if (innerClazzes != null) {
        for (Class inner : innerClazzes) {
            if (!inner.isAnonymousClass())
                return inner;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: you can cast the `bArray` to an `Object[]` and iterate over that normally

Comment: Could you provide what you already tried?

Comment: Obfuscation and reflection are usually mutually exclusive. You can exclude selected classes from obfuscation to retain reflection-ability. Instead of classForName(), use class literals (e.g. Integer.class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) instances are not types in the sense of the Java programming language. They are just objects. So you can’t do

```
Class ABArray = Array.newInstance(AB, 0).getClass();
ABArray myABArray = (ABArray)stealAndGetField(myA, ABArray);
```

because `ABArray` is just an object of type `Class`, not a type. If it were a type, it wouldn’t help anyway as the type you are trying to use is not accessible from that code. Which is what your attempt is all about, you are trying to access a `private` class which is not possible using normal Java language constructs. But you can just use `Object[]` as `A.B[]` is a subclass of `Object[]`:

```
A myA = new A();
Class AB = stealNamedInnerClass(A.class);
Class ABArray = Array.newInstance(AB, 0).getClass();
Object[] myABArray = (Object[])stealAndGetField(myA, ABArray);
```

Note that processing the elements as `Object` is no problem as you will (and can) access them via reflection only and the reflection methods take `Object` as input anyway. Of course, you will lose compile-time type safety and detect mistakes at runtime only but that’s an unavoidable limitation of reflection.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can simply iterate over your bArray:

```
// First, get bArray
Class<A> aClass = A.class;
A instance = new A();
Class<?> bClass = aClass.getDeclaredClasses()[0];
Field field = aClass.getDeclaredField("bArray");
field.setAccessible(true);
Object[] bArray = (Object[]) field.get(instance);

// Then iterate and get field value
Field xField = bClass.getDeclaredField("theX");
xField.setAccessible(true);
Field yField = bClass.getDeclaredField("theY");
yField.setAccessible(true);
for (int i = 0; i < bArray.length; ++i) {
    Object bInstance = bArray[i];
    System.out.println("Item " + i + ": [x = " + xField.get(bInstance) + ", y = " + yField.get(bInstance) + "]");
}
```

When you are testing it, make sure your array is fully initialized (i.e. contains non-null values).